# Split query results into unique sets

Tags: c#, graph, t-sql

I have a query which is returning two columns which represents the relationship between two entities (direct or indirect), for example the relationships show in the graph to the right would be represented by the data in the table to the right:

```
| From | To |          1    3    4
|------|----|          o----o----o
| 1    | 3  |              / \
| 1    | 4  |             /   \
| 1    | 5  |          2 o     o 5
| 2    | 3  |                     
| 2    | 4  |
| 2    | 5  |
| 3    | 4  |          6    7
| 3    | 5  |          o----o
| 6    | 7  |
```

What I want to do is group this data into a number of sets, equal to the number of distinct graphs described by the relationships (so 2 sets in the above example).

This grouping could happen as part of the database query (T-SQL) or once the data is in memory (C#).

Comment: I assume 1 to/from 5 is a mistake in your example?  Or if it isn't, there should also be 4 to/from 2.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I had missed the 2 to 4 relationship. I've updated the question to include that link.

Comment: Looks like you need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)

Comment: Also shouldn't there be a entry in the table for (From:1, To:2), (From:2, To:1), (From:3, to:1), (From:4, To:1) I think if all the relations are completed entered in the table then using a CTE to navigate and finding gaps (or islands) is possible. If you check SQL Server Internals books there is a solution on finding gaps/islands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be pretty, but this will group the vertexes properly and only requires edges as a starting point. Note that the order of the vertexes for an edge does not matter.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Edges as Table ( Vertex1 Int, Vertex2 Int );
insert into @Edges ( Vertex1, Vertex2 ) values
  ( 1, 3 ), ( 3, 4 ), ( 3, 2 ), ( 3, 5 ),
  ( 6, 7 );
select * from @Edges;

-- Create a working table that assigns each vertex to a unique "set".
declare @Sets as Table ( SetId Int, Vertex Int );
insert into @Sets ( SetId, Vertex )
  select Row_Number() over ( order by Vertex ), Vertex from (
    select distinct Vertex1 as Vertex from @Edges
    union
    select distinct Vertex2 from @Edges ) as PH;
select * from @Sets;

-- Update the working table to group vertexes into sets:
--   For each vertex update the   SetId  to the minimum   SetId  of all of the vertexes one edge away.
--   Repeat until nothing changes.
declare @UpdatedRows as Int = 42;
while @UpdatedRows > 0
  begin
  update NS
    set SetId = MinSetId
    from (
      select S.SetId, S.Vertex,
        ( select Min( SetId ) from @Sets where Vertex in (
          select S.Vertex union
          select Vertex1 from @Edges where Vertex2 = S.Vertex union
          select Vertex2 from @Edges where Vertex1 = S.Vertex )
          ) as MinSetId
        from @Sets as S ) as NS
    where SetId != MinSetId;
  set @UpdatedRows = @@RowCount;
  select * from @Sets;  -- Show the work as it progresses.
  end

  -- The   SetId   values can be collapsed using   Dense_Rank .
  select Dense_Rank() over ( order by SetId ) as SetId, Vertex
    from @Sets;
```

Comment: I ended up solving this in a similar way in the data access code (C#) but thank you @HABO for the mind bending SQL!